# Replicate click inside contenteditable <div> with spellcheck

Tags: javascript, jquery

Chrome's native spell check won't work on a contenteditable `<div>` unless the user clicks into the `<div>`, which makes sense. But if I'm adding a contenteditable `<div>` dynamically, is there a way to replicate a user clicking into the `<div>`> so that the spell check will work? I tried using jQuery:

```
 $('#div-id').click();
```

and

```
 $('#div-id').trigger('click');
```

but these didn't work. Any help? jQuery or JavaScript works for me.

Comment: Do you mean [`.focus()`](http://plnkr.co/edit/HQxMT6SQiFnl5qyEb9eG?p=preview)?

Comment: Dude, you're the bomb. That's why we have smart people in this world, to help us beginners.

Answer (score 2):

As a comment mentioned, bringing focus to the element programmatically will work to enable spellcheck. But this might be undesirable due to the focus now being changed to another element. So here is a complete solution (not using jQuery but will still work with it):

```
var oldFocus = document.activeElement;

div.focus();

if (oldFocus) {
    oldFocus.focus();
} else {
    div.blur();
}
```

This saves the previously focused element before focusing the div in order to enable spellcheck. Then, the focus is returned to the old element (if there was one that already had focus), otherwise it makes nothing focused.

Comment: @JackVawdrey If this answer solved your problem, consider marking it as the accepted one so that the question shows up as resolved.